# Repeated data on inserted rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, gaps-and-islands

```
--demo setup 
drop table if exists dbo.product
go

create table dbo.Product
(
    ProductId int,
    ProductTitle varchar(55),
    ProductCategory varchar(255),
    Loaddate datetime
)

insert into dbo.Product
values (1, 'Table', 'ABCD', '3/4/2018'),
       (1, 'Table', 'ABCD', '3/5/2018'),
       (1, 'Table', 'ABCD', '3/6/2018'),
       (1, 'Table', 'XYZ', '3/7/2018'),
       (1, 'Table', 'XYZ', '3/8/2018'),
       (1, 'Table', 'XYZ', '3/9/2018'),
       (1, 'Table', 'GHI', '3/10/2018'),
       (1, 'Table', 'GHI', '3/11/2018'),
       (1, 'Table', 'XYZ', '3/12/2018'),
       (1, 'Table', 'XYZ', '3/13/2018')
 
SELECT 
    product.productid, 
    product.producttitle, 
    product.productcategory, 
    MIN(product.loaddate) AS BeginDate, 
    -- ,max(product.LoadDate) as BeginDate1 
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(product.loaddate) = MAX(oa.enddate1) 
            THEN '12/31/9999' 
            ELSE MAX(product.loaddate) 
    END AS EndDate 
FROM   
    dbo.product product 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT MAX(subproduct.loaddate) EndDate1 
     FROM dbo.product subproduct 
     WHERE subproduct.productid = product.productid) oa 
GROUP BY 
    productid, producttitle, productcategory
```

Output:

| productid | producttitle | productcategory | BeginDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Table | ABCD | 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 | 2018-03-06 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Table | XYZ | 2018-03-07 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Table | GHI | 2018-03-10 00:00:00.000 | 2018-03-11 00:00:00.000 |

Desired output:

| productid | producttitle | productcategory | BeginDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Table | ABCD | 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 | 2018-03-06 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Table | XYZ | 2018-03-07 00:00:00.000 | 2018-03-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Table | GHI | 2018-03-10 00:00:00.000 | 2018-03-11 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Table | XYZ | 2018-03-12 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |

The last two inserted rows repeat the data from Loaddate '3/7/2018'-'3/9/2018', this doesn't happen if any of the new inserted rows doesn't repeat data. The only thing that changes is the LoadDate, giving me incorrect output. how can i get something like that desired output?

Comment: This looks like a gaps and islands problem; searching the term may give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: "The last inserted row has repeated data, this doesn't happen if any of the new inserted rows doesn't repeat data"  What are you (trying) to say ?

Comment: thx will look at that gaps and islands problem.  i updated my question in the end @Luuk

Comment: Can you add info on what you are trying to do? It is still pretty unclear. You are saying "I am inserting some data" and "It is giving incorrect output", but info on what you are trying to do seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you need to find a sequence number over all your records. If you already have a primary key, that's good. In example you gave us, there's no such column, so let's generate it.
Then, we make pairs with start and end dates for each product's category change. Another thing is to group all these product's category changes.
Finally, we make just a simple group by:

```
;
with cte as (   select  *,
                        row_number() over(partition by ProductId order by Loaddate) as rn
                from product 
), cte2 as (    select  t1.ProductId, 
                        t1.ProductTitle, 
                        t1.ProductCategory, 
                        t1.Loaddate                         as BeginDate,  
                        case 
                            when t1.ProductCategory <> t2.ProductCategory
                            then t1.Loaddate
                            else coalesce(t2.Loaddate, null) 
                        end as EndDate,
                        row_number() over(order by t1.ProductId, t1.Loaddate)                                   as rn_overall,
                        row_number() over(partition by t1.ProductId, t1.ProductCategory order by t1.Loaddate)   as rn_category
                from cte as t1
                    left join cte as t2
                        on t2.ProductId = t1.ProductId
                        and t2.rn = t1.rn + 1
), cte3 as (    select  *, 
                        min(rn_overall) over (partition by ProductId, ProductCategory, rn_overall - rn_category) as product_group
                from cte2
)

select  ProductId, ProductTitle, ProductCategory, 
        min(BeginDate) as BeginDate, 
        case 
            when max(case when EndDate is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
            then max(EndDate)
            else null
        end as EndDate
from cte3
group by ProductId, ProductTitle, ProductCategory, product_group
order by ProductId, BeginDate
```

Comment: looks like your query is working as it should be  Andrey.  I just noticed however that it is not displaying '12/31/9999' in the EndDate. it still displays '2018-03-13'. i wanted it to display 'Null' so i replaced it with '12/31/9999' but still nothing. do you have any idea why it is doing this?  i also tested on a table that has 290K rows. the query took like 3 minutes. not sure why so  much time. but thx anyway

Comment: @rafamaniac I fixed that issue with open EndDate, please check the query again. Regarding performance, it's low mostly because of ordering in window functions. You can play with indexes. I'd say that adding an index on ProductId + Loaddate might speed it up a bit. Also, if you have a physical column to replace any row_number() used, it will increase performance probably even better.

Comment: Hi Andrey, your code is working 100%. However i just want to replace '12/31/9999' with "Null" but if i replace it like this - coalesce(t2.Loaddate, NULL) the "EndDate" is different in this table and in a test table that i have with many rows. this doesn't happen with '12/31/9999'. Do you know how can i do this?

Comment: @rafamaniac It happens, because in the last select there's an aggregation max(EndDate) which ignores NULL values.  I edited my answer with a check for such cases, so please check it again